# Is a question requesting on understanding the Hashkafa of "X" a suitable question for Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

(*Just wondering before I possibly ask*)

Without being political, would asking a question regarding the Hashkafa of an iconic figure in Judaism or larger community within the Jewish world a suitable question to ask about on Mi Yodeya?

Answer (score 4):

I would think that if the figure is indicative of Judaism itself, it would be on topic and otherwise off-topic.

For example, the question of what Rabbi Akiva or Rav Saadya Gaon held about free will, is on topic, and Judaism; not Jews. So to, a question about their position on a halakhic matter would be on topic.

A question about what Sigmund Freud or Milo Yiannopoulos hold about free-will would not be on topic, since the question of their view is a question about Jews; not Judaism.

I realize that this is an inherently subjective definition.